# HTML and CSS margins

Tags: html, css

So again my problem seems simple but yet I havent been able to completly fix my problem. I am working on a website, I have made the body fit the full HTML yet I have a problem maybe with a right margin even though I have check them my page is too big to the right ans sends a div named container to the far right

```js
var ddsmoothmenu={

//Specify full URL to down and right arrow images (23 is padding-right added to top level LIs with drop downs):
arrowimages: {down:["downarrowclass", "./_images/down.gif", 23], right:["rightarrowclass", "./_images/right.gif", 6], left:['leftarrowclass', 'left.gif']},
transition: {overtime:300, outtime:300}, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds
shadow: {enable:true, offsetx:5, offsety:5}, //enable shadow?
showhidedelay: {showdelay: 100, hidedelay: 200}, //set delay in milliseconds before sub menus appear and disappear, respectively

///////Stop configuring beyond here///////////////////////////

detectwebkit: navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("applewebkit")!=-1, //detect WebKit browsers (Safari, Chrome etc)
detectie6: document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
css3support: window.msPerformance || (!document.all && document.querySelector), //detect browsers that support CSS3 box shadows (ie9+ or FF3.5+, Safari3+, Chrome etc)

getajaxmenu:function($, setting){ //function to fetch external page containing the panel DIVs
 var $menucontainer=$('#'+setting.contentsource[0]) //reference empty div on page that will hold menu
 $menucontainer.html("Loading Menu...")
 $.ajax({
  url: setting.contentsource[1], //path to external menu file
  async: true,
  error:function(ajaxrequest){
   $menucontainer.html('Error fetching content. Server Response: '+ajaxrequest.responseText)
  },
  success:function(content){
   $menucontainer.html(content)
   ddsmoothmenu.buildmenu($, setting)
  }
 })
},


buildmenu:function($, setting){
 var smoothmenu=ddsmoothmenu
 var $mainmenu=$("#"+setting.mainmenuid+">ul") //reference main menu UL
 $mainmenu.parent().get(0).className=setting.classname || "ddsmoothmenu"
 var $headers=$mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
 $headers.hover(
  function(e){
   $(this).children('a:eq(0)').addClass('selected')
  },
  function(e){
   $(this).children('a:eq(0)').removeClass('selected')
  }
 )
 $headers.each(function(i){ //loop through each LI header
  var $curobj=$(this).css({zIndex: 100-i}) //reference current LI header
  var $subul=$(this).find('ul:eq(0)').css({display:'block'})
  $subul.data('timers', {})
  this._dimensions={w:this.offsetWidth, h:this.offsetHeight, subulw:$subul.outerWidth(), subulh:$subul.outerHeight()}
  this.istopheader=$curobj.parents("ul").length==1? true : false //is top level header?
  $subul.css({top:this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? this._dimensions.h+"px" : 0})
  $curobj.children("a:eq(0)").css(this.istopheader? {paddingRight: smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[2]} : {}).append( //add arrow images
   '<img src="'+ (this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[1] : smoothmenu.arrowimages.right[1])
   +'" class="' + (this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[0] : smoothmenu.arrowimages.right[0])
   + '" style="border:0;" />'
  )
  if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && !smoothmenu.css3support){ //if shadows enabled and browser doesn't support CSS3 box shadows
   this._shadowoffset={x:(this.istopheader?$subul.offset().left+smoothmenu.shadow.offsetx : this._dimensions.w), y:(this.istopheader? $subul.offset().top+smoothmenu.shadow.offsety : $curobj.position().top)} //store this shadow's offsets
   if (this.istopheader)
    $parentshadow=$(document.body)
   else{
    var $parentLi=$curobj.parents("li:eq(0)")
    $parentshadow=$parentLi.get(0).$shadow
   }
   this.$shadow=$('<div class="ddshadow'+(this.istopheader? ' toplevelshadow' : '')+'"></div>').prependTo($parentshadow).css({left:this._shadowoffset.x+'px', top:this._shadowoffset.y+'px'})  //insert shadow DIV and set it to parent node for the next shadow div
  }
  $curobj.hover(
   function(e){
    var $targetul=$subul //reference UL to reveal
    var header=$curobj.get(0) //reference header LI as DOM object
    clearTimeout($targetul.data('timers').hidetimer)
    $targetul.data('timers').showtimer=setTimeout(function(){
     header._offsets={left:$curobj.offset().left, top:$curobj.offset().top}
     var menuleft=header.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? 0 : header._dimensions.w
     menuleft=(header._offsets.left+menuleft+header._dimensions.subulw>$(window).width())? (header.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? -header._dimensions.subulw+header._dimensions.w : -header._dimensions.w) : menuleft //calculate this sub menu's offsets from its parent
     if ($targetul.queue().length<=1){ //if 1 or less queued animations
      $targetul.css({left:menuleft+"px", width:header._dimensions.subulw+'px'}).animate({height:'show',opacity:'show'}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.overtime)
      if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && !smoothmenu.css3support){
       var shadowleft=header.istopheader? $targetul.offset().left+ddsmoothmenu.shadow.offsetx : menuleft
       var shadowtop=header.istopheader?$targetul.offset().top+smoothmenu.shadow.offsety : header._shadowoffset.y
       if (!header.istopheader && ddsmoothmenu.detectwebkit){ //in WebKit browsers, restore shadow's opacity to full
        header.$shadow.css({opacity:1})
       }
       header.$shadow.css({overflow:'', width:header._dimensions.subulw+'px', left:shadowleft+'px', top:shadowtop+'px'}).animate({height:header._dimensions.subulh+'px'}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.overtime)
      }
     }
    }, ddsmoothmenu.showhidedelay.showdelay)
   },
   function(e){
    var $targetul=$subul
    var header=$curobj.get(0)
    clearTimeout($targetul.data('timers').showtimer)
    $targetul.data('timers').hidetimer=setTimeout(function(){
     $targetul.animate({height:'hide', opacity:'hide'}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.outtime)
     if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && !smoothmenu.css3support){
      if (ddsmoothmenu.detectwebkit){ //in WebKit browsers, set first child shadow's opacity to 0, as "overflow:hidden" doesn't work in them
       header.$shadow.children('div:eq(0)').css({opacity:0})
      }
      header.$shadow.css({overflow:'hidden'}).animate({height:0}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.outtime)
     }
    }, ddsmoothmenu.showhidedelay.hidedelay)
   }
  ) //end hover
 }) //end $headers.each()
 if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && smoothmenu.css3support){ //if shadows enabled and browser supports CSS3 shadows
  var $toplevelul=$('#'+setting.mainmenuid+' ul li ul')
  var css3shadow=parseInt(smoothmenu.shadow.offsetx)+"px "+parseInt(smoothmenu.shadow.offsety)+"px 5px #aaa" //construct CSS3 box-shadow value
  var shadowprop=["boxShadow", "MozBoxShadow", "WebkitBoxShadow", "MsBoxShadow"] //possible vendor specific CSS3 shadow properties
  for (var i=0; i<shadowprop.length; i++){
   $toplevelul.css(shadowprop[i], css3shadow)
  }
 }
 $mainmenu.find("ul").css({display:'none', visibility:'visible'})
},

init:function(setting){
 if (typeof setting.customtheme=="object" && setting.customtheme.length==2){ //override default menu colors (default/hover) with custom set?
  var mainmenuid='#'+setting.mainmenuid
  var mainselector=(setting.orientation=="v")? mainmenuid : mainmenuid+', '+mainmenuid
  document.write('<style type="text/css">\n'
   +mainselector+' ul li a {background:'+setting.customtheme[0]+';}\n'
   +mainmenuid+' ul li a:hover {background:'+setting.customtheme[1]+';}\n'
  +'</style>')
 }
 this.shadow.enable=(document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest)? false : this.shadow.enable //in IE6, always disable shadow
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //ajax menu?
  if (typeof setting.contentsource=="object"){ //if external ajax menu
   ddsmoothmenu.getajaxmenu($, setting)
  }
  else{ //else if markup menu
   ddsmoothmenu.buildmenu($, setting)
  }
 })
}

} //end ddsmoothmenu variable
```

```css
    @charset "utf-8";

body {
 background-color: #FDFDFD;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #000;
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.4;
 width: 100%;
 background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.logo{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 height: 170px;
 width: 350px;
 }
/* ~~ Selectores de elemento/etiqueta ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { /* Debido a las diferencias existentes entre los navegadores, es recomendable no añadir relleno ni márgenes en las listas. Para lograr coherencia, puede especificar las cantidades deseadas aquí o en los elementos de lista (LI, DT, DD) que contienen. Recuerde que lo que haga aquí se aplicará en cascada en la lista .nav, a no ser que escriba un selector más específico. */
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
 margin-top: 0;/* la eliminación del margen superior resuelve un problema que origina que los márgenes escapen de la etiqueta div contenedora. El margen inferior restante lo mantendrá separado de los elementos de que le sigan. */
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;/* la adición de relleno a los lados del elemento dentro de las divs, en lugar de en las divs propiamente dichas, elimina todas las matemáticas de modelo de cuadro. Una div anidada con relleno lateral también puede usarse como método alternativo. */
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
a img { /* este selector elimina el borde azul predeterminado que se muestra en algunos navegadores alrededor de una imagen cuando está rodeada por un vínculo */
 border: none;
}

/* ~~ La aplicación de estilo a los vínculos del sitio debe permanecer en este orden (incluido el grupo de selectores que crea el efecto hover -paso por encima-). ~~ */
a:link {
 color: #42413C;
 text-decoration: underline; /* a no ser que aplique estilos a los vínculos para que tengan un aspecto muy exclusivo, es recomendable proporcionar subrayados para facilitar una identificación visual rápida */
}
a:visited {
 color: #6E6C64;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { /* este grupo de selectores proporcionará a un usuario que navegue mediante el teclado la misma experiencia de hover (paso por encima) que experimenta un usuario que emplea un ratón. */
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* ~~ este contenedor de anchura fija rodea a las demás divs ~~ */
.container {
 width: 1007px;
 height: 1152px;
 background-color: #535353;
 margin: 0 auto;/* el valor automático de los lados, unido a la anchura, centra el diseño *//* Rounded corners */
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

/* ~~ no se asigna una anchura al encabezado. Se extenderá por toda la anchura del diseño. Contiene un marcador de posición de imagen que debe sustituirse por su propio logotipo vinculado ~~ */
.header {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 221px;/* Rounded corners */
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 font-size: 100px;
 background-image: url(../_images/header1.jpg);
 width: 961px;
 margin-top: 1px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* ~~ Estas son las columnas para el diseño. ~~ 

1) El relleno sólo se sitúa en la parte superior y/o inferior de las divs. Los elementos situados dentro de estas divs tienen relleno a los lados. Esto le ahorra las "matemáticas de modelo de cuadro". Recuerde que si añade relleno o borde lateral a la div propiamente dicha, éste se añadirá a la anchura que defina para crear la anchura *total*. También puede optar por eliminar el relleno del elemento en la div y colocar una segunda div dentro de ésta sin anchura y el relleno necesario para el diseño deseado. También puede optar por eliminar el relleno del elemento en la div y colocar una segunda div dentro de ésta sin anchura y el relleno necesario para el diseño deseado.

2) No se asigna margen a las columnas, ya que todas ellas son flotantes. Si es preciso añadir un margen, evite colocarlo en el lado hacia el que se produce la flotación (por ejemplo: un margen derecho en una div configurada para flotar hacia la derecha). En muchas ocasiones, puede usarse relleno como alternativa. En el caso de divs para las que deba incumplirse esta regla, deberá añadir una declaración "display:inline" a la regla de la div para evitar un error que provoca que algunas versiones de Internet Explorer dupliquen el margen.

3) Dado que las clases se pueden usar varias veces en un documento (y que también se pueden aplicar varias clases a un elemento), se ha asignado a las columnas nombres de clases en lugar de ID. Por ejemplo, dos divs de barra lateral podrían apilarse si fuera necesario. Si lo prefiere, éstas pueden cambiarse a ID fácilmente, siempre y cuando las utilice una sola vez por documento.

4) Si prefiere que la navegación esté a la derecha en lugar de a la izquierda, simplemente haga que estas columnas floten en dirección opuesta (todas a la derecha en lugar de todas a la izquierda) y éstas se representarán en orden inverso. No es necesario mover las divs por el código fuente HTML.

*/
.sidebar1 {
 float: left;
 width: 660px;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-left: 21px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-left: 0;/* Rounded corners */
 border-radius: 10px;
 word-spacing: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.content {
 width: 288px;
 float: right;/* Rounded corners */
 border-radius: 10px;
 word-spacing: 5px;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-right: 21px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 padding-left: 0;
}

/* ~~ Este selector agrupado da espacio a las listas del área de .content ~~ */
.content ul, .content ol { 
 padding: 0 15px 15px 40px; /* este relleno reproduce en espejo el relleno derecho de la regla de encabezados y de párrafo incluida más arriba. El relleno se ha colocado en la parte inferior para que el espacio existente entre otros elementos de la lista y a la izquierda cree la sangría. Estos pueden ajustarse como se desee. */
}

/* ~~ Los estilos de lista de navegación (pueden eliminarse si opta por usar un menú desplegable predefinido como el de Spry) ~~ */
ul.nav {
 list-style: none; /* esto elimina el marcador de lista */
 border-top: 1px solid #666; /* esto crea el borde superior de los vínculos (los demás se sitúan usando un borde inferior en el LI) */
 margin-bottom: 15px; /* esto crea el espacio entre la navegación en el contenido situado debajo */
}
ul.nav li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #666; /* esto crea la separación de los botones */
}
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited { /* al agrupar estos selectores, se asegurará de que los vínculos mantengan el aspecto de botón incluso después de haber sido visitados */
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
 display: block; /* esto asigna propiedades de bloque al vínculo, lo que provoca que llene todo el LI que lo contiene. Esto provoca que toda el área reaccione a un clic de ratón. */
 width: 160px;  /*esta anchura hace que se pueda hacer clic en todo el botón para IE6. Puede eliminarse si no es necesario proporcionar compatibilidad con IE6. Calcule la anchura adecuada restando el relleno de este vínculo de la anchura del contenedor de barra lateral. */
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #C6D580;
}
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus { /* esto cambia el color de fondo y del texto tanto para usuarios que naveguen con ratón como para los que lo hagan con teclado */
 background-color: #ADB96E;
 color: #FFF;
}

/* ~~ El pie de página ~~ */
.footer {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 color: #FFFFFF;/* esto da a IE6 hasLayout para borrar correctamente */
 clear: both;/* esta propiedad de borrado fuerza a .container a conocer dónde terminan las columnas y a contenerlas */
 width: 986px;
 height: 53px;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-bottom: 6px;
 padding-left: 0;/* Rounded corners */
 border-radius: 10px;
 word-spacing: 5px;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 500;
}

/* ~~ clases float/clear varias ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* esta clase puede utilizarse para que un elemento flote en la parte derecha de la página. El elemento flotante debe preceder al elemento junto al que debe aparecer en la página. */
 float: right;
 margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* esta clase puede utilizarse para que un elemento flote en la parte izquierda de la página. El elemento flotante debe preceder al elemento junto al que debe aparecer en la página. */
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* esta clase puede situarse en una <br /> o div vacía como elemento final tras la última div flotante (dentro de #container) si #footer se elimina o se saca fuera de #container */
 clear:both;
 height:0;
 font-size: 1px;
 line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/BasicTemplate.dwt.php" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>E-Recycling.dk</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<link href="_css/MainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/ddsmoothmenu.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/ddsmoothmenu-v.css" type="text/css" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
 font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/ddsmoothmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ddsmoothmenu.init({
 mainmenuid: "smoothmenu1", //menu DIV id
 orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
 classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
 contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
})
</script>

<?php include("_include/google.php"); ?>
</head>

<body leftmargin="100">

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Top region" -->
    <?php include("_include/header.php"); ?>
    <div class="clearfloat">
      <?php include("_include/menu.php"); ?>
      <?php include("_include/slider.php"); ?>
    </div>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="left region" -->
<div class="sidebar1">
<p>&nbsp; </p>
  <h1>Problem Statement</h1>

  
  <p>The problem of an almost non existing online  commercial market for recyclable products in the construction and demolition  business in Denmark at a major scale for everybody&rsquo;s access was first  introduced to us and a group of classmates by Thea Lyng Thomsen, a  Representative of the Skive Kommune, during the 2015 technology business model  and innovation TBMI challenge.</p>
  
 <p> During this challenge, as a group, we witnessed  the lack of shared information that there is in the buying, selling and  disposal of waste. Also during the duration of the challenge we held meetings  with a local company and an entrepreneur dealing with the exchange of waste in  different levels of the construction business market and their relations, in  order to conclude that some sort of information system that would enable an  easy exchange of information could bust up sales and create new connections  within companies</p>
  <!-- end .sidebar1 -->
</div>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable --><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="right region" -->
<div class="content">
  <h1>Right Region</h1>
  
  
  <!-- end .content -->
</div>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<div class="footer">
    <?php include("_include/footer.php"); ?></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Comment: So in simple words - what is your problem exactly? And on what browser are you experiencing your issues?

Comment: I want the elements to cover the full HTML page without blank space on the sides. I am using dreamweaver/chrome

Comment: OK - so which elements? I guess "blank space" you are talking about are margins around "Problem Statement" & "Right Region" areas?

Comment: I mean on the sides outside of the .content

Comment: You sure you need ALL that code to reproduce your issue? ;)

Comment: hahahaha  I added all.. just in case

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `margin-left: 21px;` from your `.sidebar1` element and `margin-right: 21px;` from `.content` element.

Comment: if I do that it just takes off from the gray area inside the body and .content not from the outside white space

Comment: Are you asking to your `.container` to span along all available width of the page? Is that what you need? If yes, then you need to start over again, by removing your `margin` instructions from that specific class, and then adjusting all sizing accordingly (`height` and `width`). If you need something to take all the width, you can accomplish that by saying: `width: 100%`, which will mean that you want this element to be as wide as its **Parent element**, in your case `body` element.